void loop() или int main() в arduino
При создании больших проектов с кодом, разделенным на разные файлы, я задался вопросом:
Является ли int main(){while(1){//код} } полной заменой void loop(){//код} для микроконтроллеров на таких камнях, как atmega и esp, может есть какие-то подводные камни? И что тогда является заменой void setup(){}?

С вопросом разобрался.

В программах для Arduino точно так же есть функция main, но она лежит в стандартной библиотеке, а пользователь просто реализует setup и loop, которые из main вызываются.
См. исходник файла main.cpp библиотеки Arduino:
int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif
    
    setup();
    
    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }
        
    return 0;
}

Вот вызов setup, вот бесконечный цикл с вызовом loop. Т.е. примерно соответствует просто бесконечному циклу, но еще обрабатываются события последовательного порта.

Интересно, почему порядок loop() и serialEventRun() именно такой, а не обратный?

Ну сразу после старта может еще никакие события не должны прийти, а потом порядок в коде уже не важен, они просто чередуются.

Спасибо за разъяснение
